# AWS cognito how to forgot password with lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I need implement logic for forgot password with aws lambda. I have cognito user pool with users and i need implement lambda for forgot password. How can i do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AWS SDK to invoke the Cognito-forgot password from LAMBDA. you can refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html) documentation. You may have to provide the User pool Client and Username of the user along with the request.

Note: Your Lambda execution policy should have `cognito-idp:ForgotPassword`

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#forgotPassword-property) is the Documentation for implementing with Nodejs.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

export.handler = async (event) => {

    const params = {
        ClientId: 'USER POOL CLIENT ID',
        Username: 'USERNAME'
    }
    const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    const response = cognitoidentityserviceprovider.forgotPassword(params).promise();

    return response;
}
```

Comment: how can i invoke this lambda from cognito? not from api gateway.

Comment: @PROCODE cognito is a service to be used by end layers, you call cognito services in your api and request page, not the other way around

Comment: but how can i trigger lambda by cognito forgot password?

Comment: @PROCODE You can use the gateway to trigger lambda functions. The flow will be Gateway --> Lambda --> Cognito.